# Promise not returned from recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

### Background

I have a problem where my promise is not being returned to its calling function. I know this would usually work, but it's not when inside a recursive function. The resolve is being called and I can see the function `FindElementById` is finding the element correctly, however the call in the thenable `UpdateMasterMenuItem(result, queuedItem)` is not being called.

What am I doing in my code snippets, what am I trying to do?

Loop over a collection `queuedItems` and find those items in another collection `menuItems`. I do this by passing in the Id of the item I'm trying to find, as well as the collection it's in, into a recursive function `FindElementById`. When the item is found, I'm returning the found item and doing some other stuff to it in the function `UpdateMasterMenuItem`.

### Code

```
// Calling Loop
        queuedItems.forEach(function (queuedItem) {
            FindElementById(queuedItem.dataset.id, menuItems).then(function(result) {
                UpdateMasterMenuItem(result, queuedItem);
            });
        });


// Recursive Function
function FindElementById(id, menuItems) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        menuItems.forEach(function (menuItem) {
            if (menuItem.Id === id) {
                return resolve(menuItem);

            } else if (menuItem.Child.length > 0) {
                FindElementById(id, menuItem.Child);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `FindElementById` returns a promise? There's nothing asynchronous going on in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues comes from the `else if` block: when you recursively invoke the method by itself, you also need to invoke `resolve()` once nested promise is resolved: otherwise the `.then()` callback will never fire.

```
function FindElementById(id, menuItems) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        menuItems.forEach(function (menuItem) {
            if (menuItem.Id === id) {
                return resolve(menuItem);

            } else if (menuItem.Child.length > 0) {
                // You also need to remember to resolve here!
                FindElementById(id, menuItem.Child).then(nestedMenuitem => resolve(nestedMenuitem));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

However, there is an issue: **the promise can only be resolved once**. So, your promise is actually **resolved at the first iteration of the `forEach` loop if the condition is satisfied**. Is that what you want? If the ID is indeed truly unique, or that in the event of duplicate IDs you only want to return the first instance, then this is okay.

This brings us back to my comment: your function is not doing any asynchronous operation, so it is probably easier to make do without promises altogether:

```
function FindElementById(id, menuItems) {
    let el;
    for (let menuItem of menuItems) {
        if (menuItem.Id === id) {
            el = menuItem;
            break;
        } else {
            el = FindElementById(id, menuItem.Child)
        }
    }

    return el;
}
```

Comment: Great points. Upon reflection it seems I decided to try using a promise as a solution to a problem that I didn't properly understand.